# Longer Filenames with git merge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

So I have a Git project, and we (a mostly typical Rails project) have a pretty deep directory structure.

When I do git merge I see results like:

```
app/views/shared/exception_report.erb              |    6 +
app/views/ui/sample.html.erb                       |   11 +-
app/views/verifications/new.html.erb               |   10 +-
config/deploy.rb                                   |    2 +-
.../20100825132200_thing_pane.rb                   |   27 ++---
.../20100826210000_another_thing_pane.rb           |   21 +++
lib/semantic_form_builder_plus.rb                  |    5 +
```

The problem is that I want to see the directory `.../20100825132200_thing_pane.rb` is in. Is there a git setting that controls the number of columns these lines take?

**tl;dr** : git merge lists path names added/changed, but crops the filepath off too soon for my purposes. Can I control how many columns git uses when it prints this filename list?

**Edit for posterity's/future Googlers sake**: I took this answer and created a slick Rake task to make this really easy: [incoming_migration_check.rake](http://gist.github.com/573910).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to do that for a merge's built-in diffstat.

However, you could do this a merge with `--no-commit` followed by a `diff --stat=width,name-width` to get a wider diffstat before committing.  Alternatively you could do the diff above with a `HEAD^` argument after the merge is complete to see a wider listing of the results.

Comment: I tried various commands to get this to work, and Git (1.7.2.3) always complained: ` git diff  --stat=width,name-width HEAD^`, `git diff  --stat=width,96 HEAD^`, and ` git diff  "--stat[=width,96]" HEAD^ `. They all gave me the usage command. What am I doing wrong here? (On the good hand, `git diff --numstat POINTA..POINTB`  does work for my purposes...

Comment: You want two numbers, e.g. `git diff --stat=96,80 HEAD^` -- one to specify total width, and optionally one for the width of the name column.